# Is a function less than a decreasing function also decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Two families of functions, $f_\alpha(x)$ and $g_\alpha(x)$, where $0\leq\alpha, x\leq 1$.

It is known that  $f_\alpha(0)=g_\alpha(0)=1$ and $f_\alpha(1)=g_\alpha(1)=0$ for any $\alpha$.

Also, $f_0(x)=g_0(x)\leq 1$ and $f_1(x)=g_1(x)=1$ for any $x\in[0, 1]$.

Knowing that $g_\alpha(x)$ decreases in $x$ for any $\alpha$, can we say the same for $f_\alpha$?

Comment: Try drawing this out; you should be able to come up with an example where $f$ decreases at a faster rate in one region, then increases for a bit, then decreases again, all while being below $g$.

Answer (score 3):

Here we have $f\le g$ and $g$ is decreasing but, as you can see from the picture, nothing can be deduced regarding if $f$ is increasing or decreasing.

[image]